# FTPClient's isAvailable and is Connected return true but storeFileStream returns null

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm uploading lots of files (about 2000) using Commons-net FTPClient.
I'm checking connection before each upload using `isAvailable()` & `isConnected()` methods and reconnect if connection closed.
after uploading some files (variable) `storeFileStream` returns `null` (that means "data connection cannot be opened" as javadoc) while `isAvailable()` & `isConnected()` both are true !!
What is the problem?
How can I check data connection availability?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I check data connection availability?

Try to use it. There is no 'dial tone' in TCP, so methods with names like `isConnected()` can't do anything more than tell you (1) whether you have ever connected, and, if you're lucky, (2) whether you have subsequently closed the connection or encountered an I/O error on it. I'm not familiar with the API you mention but the `isConnected()` methods of the JDK classes don't do anything beyond (1).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try calling `getReplyCode()`.

> Returns the integer value of the reply code of the last FTP reply. You
>   will usually only use this method after you connect to the FTP server
>   to check that the connection was successful since connect is of type
>   void.

You can check what those codes mean from this [Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

Comment: getReplyCode will still return 200 even when the login totally failed. I think the only way to really tell is to attempt a list() call after you connect and see if that returns a 530 (login error)